# Selenium Web driver ( driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'https//:xyz/asd')) IS NOT WORKING .Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, webdriver

I am constantly trying to access a simple text available in `<h5>` tag but it gives `NoSuchElementException`.
I already saw that there is no `<iframe>` as a parent of this element. I am also giving `time.sleep(20)` sec which is clearly more then enough. I can see that the page is completely loaded but it give error:

```
Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/section/section/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/h5
```

I don't know what should i try or what is causing the issue.

[image]

I am trying to access "Aamer Jamal" text. but I got `NoSuchElementException`.

The code

```
time.sleep(20)
fullname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/section/section/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/h5')
print(fullname.text)
```

Comment: How did you get that xpath string?

Comment: Share your code please. Or at least the piece which is failing

Comment: time.sleep(20)    
fullname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/section/section/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/h5')
print(fullname.text)

Comment: Post the URL and the code you've tried.

Comment: if this is a public URL, would you mind sharing it with us?

Comment: This is the URL. https://www.espncricinfo.com/player/aamer-jamal-793441  where i am trying to access the name "Aamer Jamal".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to get the text under "FULL NAME":

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xpath = '//*[@id="main-container"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/h5'
    driver = WebDriver()
    driver.get('https://www.espncricinfo.com/player/aamer-jamal-793441')
    res = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).text
```